# Elasticsearch: Dismax boosts don't seem to be working

Tags: search, elasticsearch, dismax

I have a search page on my site where I'm doing a search on name fields, and I need to return wildcard and fuzzy matches as well as exact matches; however, the exact matches should be displayed higher on the page, so I'm trying to make sure that the name is EITHER an exact match, a wildcard match, or a fuzzy match, with exact matches boosted the highest and fuzzy matches boosted lowest. By suggestion I'm using a dis_max query, so that for each name field I have a separate dis_max. For simplicity, I've only included one of my dis_max's in the example query below, but if I was also searching on first_name, I would have a second dis_max in the "must" for "first_name".

```
{
  "query": {
      "filtered": {
          "query": {
              "bool": {
                  "must": [
                      {
                          "dis_max": {
                              "queries": [
                                  {
                                      "match": {
                                          "last_name": {
                                              "type": "phrase",
                                              "query": "COTTER",
                                              "analyzer": "standard",
                                              "boost": 10000
                                          }
                                      }
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "query_string": {
                                          "query": "COTTER",
                                          "default_field": "last_name",
                                          "boost": 0.05
                                      }
                                  },
                                  {
                                      "match": {
                                          "last_name": {
                                              "query": "COTTER",
                                              "fuzziness": 2,
                                              "boost": 0.001,
                                              "analyzer": "standard",
                                              "fuzziness": 2,
                                              "prefix_length": 1
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              ]
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

The problem is that the boosts don't seem to be working. When I remove the second two queries in the dis_max and only do the phrase match for "Cotter," I get results with last_name "Cotter." However, when I use all three queries, the first results I get are "Carter" and "Carder"... the fuzzy matches are being ranked higher (or equal) to the exact matches, even though the boost on the fuzzy matches is 0.001 and the boost on the exact match is 10000. I also tried with values 0.1 and 1 respectively, but got the same results... it doesn't seem to matter how small or big I make the boosts.

Comment: That query you have works for me. I suggest taking it out of your larger query and test just this bit - the one with the "last_name". It may be that some other parts of your query influences the overall score.

Comment: I am testing it with just last_name

Comment: Then post the mapping of that index.

Comment: Specify "tie_breaker" parameter, without it dis_max query would choose the single best matching field, and ignore the other